# Slow page load with Excel database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, excel, page-load-time

I am using an Excel spreadsheet with about 1600 rows and 4 columns to populate a database for display in a Ruby app. This is resulting in a page load time of over 20 seconds. How can I improve the performance?

From db\seeds.rb:

```
oo = Excelx.new("RatingsDB.xlsx")
oo.default_sheet = oo.sheets.first

2.upto(oo.last_row) do |line|
    Rating.create(name: oo.cell(line,'B'), score: oo.cell(line,'C'), when_rated: oo.cell(line,'A'), comment: oo.cell(line,'D'))
end
```

From app\controllers\ratings_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @ratings_by_name = Rating.paginate(:order => 'name ASC', :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10, :conditions => ['name like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
    @ratings_by_score = Rating.paginate(:order => 'score DESC', :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10, :conditions => ['name like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ratings_by_name }
    end
  end
```

From app\views\ratings\index.html.erb:

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">By Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">By Score</a></li>
    <li><form class="navbar-search">
      <input type="text" class="search-query span3" placeholder="Search" name="search">
      <div class="icon-search"></div>
     </form></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <% @ratings_by_name.each do |rating| %>
      <div class="rating">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span7">
            <strong><%= rating.name %></strong>
            <div class="meta">
                | <%= link_to 'View', rating %> | 
              <span class="admin">
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_rating_path(rating) %> | 
              </span>
              Rated on <%= rating.when_rated %>
            </div>
          </div>   
          <div class="span1">
            <%= rating.score %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= will_paginate @ratings_by_name %>   
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not a ruby user, but I can tell you that MS Office interop on .NET is painfully slow. If this gem uses the same underlying COM interop, I'm not surprised it would be slow as well.

Comment: Not familiar with using Ruby to access Excel data, but there is likely some way in Ruby to grab the whole range containing your data as a 2-D array (or Ruby equivalent) and then iterate over that instead of making cell-by-cell calls over COM to Excel.

Comment: +1 @TimWilliams - Limiting the number of COM calls, in general, will improve performance.

Comment: Dump the data to a csv file, and load from that instead?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem like the OP is actually using Excel *as* the database... 20 seconds to load and display 10 rows from the database does seem really slow. Is it slow in development? Have you narrowed it down to whether the issue is with the database query or the view rendering? My first thought was to add an index, but 1600 rows isn't really that much